# where to find all the exception classes in AWS-SDK for dynamodb in NodeJS typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, amazon-dynamodb, nestjs

I am trying to insert some data into dynamodb, and as expected I am getting a `ConditionalCheckFailedException`. So I am trying to catch that exception for only that scenario, apart from that I want to throw server error for all other errors.
But to add the type, I am not able to find the `ConditionalCheckFailedException` in aws-sdk.

This is what I was trying to do.

```
// where to import this from   
try {
   await AWS.putItem(params).promise()
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof ConditionalCheckFailedException) { // unable to find this exception type in AWS SDK
    throw new Error('create error')
  } else {
    throw new Error('server error')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Udpate: aws-sdk v3

Since version v3 the property name has changed to `name`:

```
if (e.name === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') {
```

### Old post: aws-sdk v2

You can check the error by using the following guard instead:

```
if (e.code === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') {
```

Note that `instanceof` only works on classes, not on interfaces. So even if you had the type, if it was an interface you couldn't use it because it relies on certain prototype checks. Using the `err.code` property is safer.

Comment: From the aws docs this looks like java exceptions not javascript, and it would be nice to have the link to the docs to see all exception names if possible

Answer (score 16):

When you are using [aws-sdk v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/#getting-started) the error does not have a property `code`. Instead, you want to check `error.name`.

For example:

```js
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

const key = 'myKey.json';
const s3Client = new S3Client({});
const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'bucketName',
    Key: key
});

try {
    const response = await s3Client.send(command);
} catch (error) {
    if (error.name === 'NoSuchKey') {
        console.warning(`My key="${key}" was not found.`);
    } else {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per March 16th, 2022, the v3 SDK now offers exception classes you can check against:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/service-error-handling-modular-aws-sdk-js/

Example excerpt from the blog post:

```
import {
  InvalidSignatureException,
  ResourceNotFoundException,
  FooServiceException,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-foo";

try {
  await client.send(someCommand);
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof InvalidSignatureException) {
    // Handle InvalidSignatureException
  } else if (e instanceof ResourceNotFoundException) {
    // Handle ResourceNotFoundException
  } else if (e instanceof FooServiceException) {
    // Handle all other server-side exceptions from Foo service
  } else {
    // Other errors
  }
}
```